# When and why did "a" begin to precede "menudo" to indicate that it means "often"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, adverbios

Someone asked this question over on Duolingo and though I had never thought about it before, it made me wonder why, too.  I wasn't going to post a question about it here until I came across this over on Tureng:

[image]

which tells me that *menudo*, at one time, meant "often" without an "a" preceding it.  This got me curious.  So, I searched through the web a bit, but, finding nothing, I came here.  I know there's at least one or two users of this forum who enjoy etymology and specialize in such things, so I figured, why spend more time on this when I know there are others with more knowledge and better resources who could do a much more adequate job of answering such a question than I could.

*Note: This question is not about meaning (as the tags indicate).  It was formed off of an assumption that at one time the concept of "often," at one time, was expressed without an "a" preceding "menudo".  This belief is based off of [**an entry for "menudo" that was seen on Tureng**](https://tureng.com/en/spanish-english/menudo).  Tureng has proven to be a fairly reliable dictionary for me, so I am making the assumption that the information it has provided at meaning #29 is true, but I don't know that for sure.  What I want to know is: 1) Is this true?, 2) If so, when did it happen? and 3) Why?*

---

**¿Por qué una "a" precede a "menudo"?**

Alguien hizo esta pregunta en Duolingo y, aunque nunca había pensado en ello, me hizo preguntarme también por qué.  No iba a publicar una pregunta al respecto aquí hasta que me encontré con esto en Tureng:

[Véanse arriba.]

que me dice que *menudo*, en una época, significaba "a menudo" sin la "a" que lo precede.  Esto me despertó la curiosidad.  Así que busqué un poco en la red, pero, al no encontrar nada, llegué aquí.  Sé que hay al menos uno o dos usuarios de este foro a los que les gusta la etimología y se especializan en esas cosas, así que pensé que para qué pasar más tiempo en esto cuando sé que hay otros con más conocimientos y mejores recursos que podrían hacer un trabajo mucho más adecuado para responder a esa pregunta que yo.

*Nota: Esta pregunta no se refiere al significado (como indican las etiquetas).  Se formó a partir de una suposición de que en una época el concepto de "menudo" se expresaba sin una "a" que precediera a "menudo".   Esta creencia se basa en [**una entrada para "menudo" que se vio en Tureng**](https://tureng.com/en/spanish-english/menudo).  Tureng ha demostrado ser un diccionario bastante fiable para mí, así que estoy haciendo la suposición de que la información que ha proporcionado en el significado # 29 es verdadera, pero no lo sé con seguridad.  Lo que quiero saber es: 1) ¿Es esto cierto?, 2) Si es así, ¿cuándo ocurrió? y 3) ¿Por qué?*

---

*Por el amor del tiempo, esta traducción fue realizada con la versión gratuita del traductor [www.DeepL.com/Translator.](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator.)*

Comment: This kind of question merits being looked up in the RAE dictionary....For  your information, DeepL and other online translation programs are not reliable.

Comment: @Lambie  I did look it up on the RAE.  However, its entry for _a menudo_ was simply this: "1. loc. adv. Muchas veces, frecuentemente y con continuación."  It made no mention of the word's former appearance as simply _menudo_ by the same meaning — _often_.  _Menudo_ provides information for two meanings no longer in use (#9 and #14), but none of them are exactly _a menudo_.  #14 is close, but when you visit the entry for it (_por menudo_), it makes no mention of _a menudo_.  Did you even look it up before posting your comment?

Comment: Lisa, how can anything be clearer than the RAE?? **a menudo** means often or frequently, And the *main meaning* of menudo is small. Look at the bottom of the RAE page for "a menudo". When a word is part of a set expression, they put it at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @Lambie You're completely missing the reason I posted. I'm not asking for the meaning.  I know the meaning of _menudo_ and _a menudo_.  You're right, the RAE via its DLE makes that clear. What it does not address is information on whether or not _menudo_, by itself, meant _often_ at one time as the #29 entry on Tureng indicates. As you may know, the DLE undergoes changes from year to year. I am wondering if an older version of the DLE might have contained information related to the actual question I posted. I don't have access to older versions of the DLE, otherwise, I'd investigate myself.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I don't understand. So, I will pass  on it for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que la pregunta planteada es si en el pasado (y actualmente en desuso), la palabra **menudo** tenía la acepción de "frecuentemente" (=*often*), como la que tiene en la actualidad la locución adverbial "a menudo". Y todo ello basado en que así aparece en la definición vigesimonovena del diccionario [Tureng](https://tureng.com/en/spanish-english/menudo).

Creo que **no es así** por los siguientes motivos:

- "A menudo" aparece en textos españoles desde el año 1201 (de acuerdo con el CORDE) con el significado actual. En cambio, ninguna de los textos recogido en el CORDE para esa época o anteriores indican un significado para "menudo" diferente de el de "pequeño tamaño".
- En los diccionarios accesibles a través del NTLLE **anteriores a 1591**, las definiciones de "menudo" no se corresponden con "frecuentemente" o similar (por ejemplo: Nebrija, Alcalá, Casas).
- En los diccionarios accesibles a través del NTLLE **posteriores a 1604**, las definiciones de "menudo" no se corresponden con "frecuentemente" o similar, y además hay una entrada específica para "a menudo" = "frecuentemente" (por ejemplo: por ejemplo, Palet 1604, Oudin 1607, Vittori 1609).

El único caso *dudoso* que he encontrado es en la muy concisa definición del diccionario de **Percival (1591)**:

> "Menudo, a menudo, often"

que no me parece lo suficientemente clara como para deducir a partir de esto que "a menudo" = "frecuentemente". Como unas líneas antes ese mismo diccionario define:

> "Menudo, little"

podría ser que simplemente estuviera indicando que, a partir de la palabra "menudo", la construcción "a menudo" quiere decir "*often*".

A mi ver eso mismo es lo que ocurre, pero de un modo más claro, en el diccionario de 1825 de Nuñez (3ª entrada):

> MENUDO adv. ant. MENUDAMENTE || A MENUDO, Repetidamente y con continuación. || POR MENUDO, Particularmente, con mucha distinción ...

En conclusión, pienso que la palabra "menudo" no tenía **por si sola**, sin la "a" previa, la acepción de "frecuentemente" por la que la OP pregunta.

Comment: I could say that you too did not answer the question since the OP apparently wants to know when a menudo began to mean often, specifically.

Comment: @Lambie It seems u stil don't understand

Comment: Actually, Chamonix gave me a brilliant answer and to think of the research that he/she must have done to answer it really kind of blows my mind.  Excellent work, Chamonix.  Muy bien hecho.  And for that I easily award you the green check mark.

Comment: @LisaBeck: Nada comparado con tus propias respuestas, como https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/23951/how-is-pea-translated-into-spanish/23952#23952 or https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/21816/what-is-the-difference-between-catedr%c3%a1tico-docente-maestro-and-profeso/21817#21817

Answer (score 3):

They are different words with different origins.

"a menudo" means oftentimes, habitually and [comes from the latin "ad minūtim" meaning in small steps](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/a_menudo).

"menudo" which means [small and many other things](https://dle.rae.es/menudo) comes from the [latin "minūtus" meaning small](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/menudo)

Comment: They have the same Latin origin.

Comment: "minūtus" and "minūtim" share a root, but "ad minūtim" is different than "minūtus"

Comment: Look at the RAE pages, all those terms including a menudo come from minutus. Wikipedia has mistakes. The RAE does not.

Comment: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/16468/what-does-ad-min%c5%abtim-mean-does-it-mean-the-same-as-min%c5%abtus

Comment: They are **declensions**, not conjugations. Conjugations are for verbs. Declensions are for nouns. ***Del lat. minūtus***. both a menudo and menudo in the RAE., Your question on the Latin forum is not right for this question. The right question is: do menudo and a menudo come from minutes??

Comment: That's what I meant by '"minūtus" and "minūtim" share a root, but "ad minūtim" is different than "minūtus"' There is this specific meaning which that declension with "ad" from where "a menudo" comes from. The RAE just mentions the common root.

Comment: A menudo and menudo have ONLY ONE root: minutus. End of story.

Answer (score -1):

The reason it starts with **a** is because **a menudo** and **menudo** do not have the same meaning

a menudo

1. loc. adv. Muchas veces, frecuentemente y con continuación.

An adverb.

Whereas the adjectives and other meanings do not take **a**.

1. adj. De pequeño tamaño.

Too many to list.

[Diccionario de la lengua española](https://dle.rae.es/menudo)

Comment: -1 This is not an answer to the OP question

Comment: @Sisifo Yes, I said this days ago: "Yeah, I guess I don't understand. So, I will pass on it for now" But I have to say that your citing the year 1201 also does not answer it, I guess.